# While loop replace in SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2014

Please read below code, i used while loop for getting top 30 by decreasing ADTV criteria by 10%, will continue to decrease until i get top 30. I would like to replace while loop

```
DECLARE
@parent_symbol NVARCHAR(20) = 'SXXE',
@index_symbol NVARCHAR(20) = 'ISX30P',
@top50_symbol NVARCHAR(20) = 'SX5E',
@true CHAR(4) = 'TRUE',
@false CHAR(5) = 'FALSE',
@top INT = 30,
@adtv_filter INT = 30000000,
@sector_max INT=6,
@count INT,
@adtv INT,
@remainingCount INT;

--select * from universe_temp where selection_flag = 'TRUE'
--Delete from universe_temp
    SET @count= (SELECT COUNT(dj_id) 
FROM universe_temp 
WHERE selection_flag= @true);
print(@count)
--while (@count<@top)
set @adtv = @adtv_filter-((10*@adtv_filter)/100)
print(@adtv)

set @remainingCount = @top-@count
print(@remainingCount)
while (@count<@top)
Begin
;with remaining_top as (
select top(@remainingCount) dj_id from universe_temp
                         WHERE selection_flag=@false and adtv3m >= @adtv and reason_for_rejection = 'Not in Top 30'
                         ORDER BY market_capitalization_rank
)


--select * from remaining_top

UPDATE u
            SET u.selection_flag=  @true
                --,u.reason_for_rejection= CASE  WHEN t.dj_id IS NULL AND u.reason_for_rejection IS NULL THEN 'Not in Top '+CAST(@top AS NVARCHAR) ELSE reason_for_rejection END
FROM universe_temp u 
         JOIN remaining_top t ON u.dj_id=t.dj_id

set @count= @count + (select count(*) from  universe_temp where selection_flag= @true)
        End
```

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (That code is product specific.)

Comment: If you want to replace the loop, what keeps you from doing it?

Comment: The thing is i dont know how to do it. Can you help ?

Comment: SQL Server 2014 (T-SQL)

Comment: Please read [this](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question.

Answer (score 0):

There's so many problems in that script that I don't really know where to start.  One thing to bear in mind is that you are reducing your criteria outside the loop, another is that you add to your count rather than refreshing it at the end of each loop, etc.

If you are simply trying to pull out the top 30 "whatevers" by some criteria then this might help avoiding using loops?

```
--Deselect all rows
UPDATE universe_temp SET selection_flag = @false;

--Now select the top x
WITH Ranked AS (
    SELECT
        *,
        DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY adtv3m DESC, market_capitalization_rank DESC) AS rank_id 
    FROM
        universe_temp)
UPDATE
    r
SET
    selection_flag = @true
FROM
    Ranked r
WHERE
    r.rank_id <= @top;

--Find the threshold (bonus)
SELECT MIN(adtv3m) FROM universe_temp WHERE selection_flag = @true;
```

But I really have no idea what you are trying to achieve here, how you get your data into that "universe_temp" table, what this represents, etc.